# inserting data into database using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to insert data into my database using following JSP code. I have created database named music and table named tbl_user. After I have entered all the related fields in `register.jsp`, the control goes to `Insertdata.java` but data is not going into database.

**This is my JSP page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="assets/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <title>Sign UP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-default login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Register Here</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="Insertdata">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> First Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname"  name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Last Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname"  name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="adress" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address"  name="address" placeholder="Address">
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"  name="email" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-10">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"">Register</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>     
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my servlet for database connection **DatabaseConnection.java**

```
package mypackage;

import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.Statement;  


public class DatabaseConnection {  
Connection conn;  
Statement stmt;  
ResultSet res;  

public DatabaseConnection(){  

}  

public Connection setConnection(){  
try{  
    System.out.println("sdsadasd");  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/music","root","");  
 System.out.println("Connected to the database");  
}catch(Exception e){  

}  
return conn;  
}  

public ResultSet getResult(String sql,Connection conn){  
this.conn=conn;  
try{  
stmt=conn.createStatement();  
res=stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
}catch(Exception e){  

}  
return res;  
}  
}
```

This is my servlet to insert data **Insertdata.java**

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.Statement;  
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  


public class Insertdata extends HttpServlet {  

String fname,lname,address,email,password;  
String query;  
Connection conn;  
Statement stmt;  
ResultSet res;  
DatabaseConnection dbconn;  


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
throws ServletException, IOException {  
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
try {  

dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();  

//Af_Scheme_Number=request.getParameter("Af_Scheme_Number");  
fname=request.getParameter("fname");  
lname=request.getParameter("lname");  
address=request.getParameter("address");  
email=request.getParameter("email");  
password=request.getParameter("password");  

conn=dbconn.setConnection();  

stmt=conn.createStatement();  
query= "insert into tbl_user(first_name,last_name,address,email,password)"+  
" values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+address+"',"+email+",'"+ password+"')";  
int i=stmt.executeUpdate(query);  

} catch(Exception e){  

    System.out.println("Error");  

}finally {  

out.close();  
}  
}  


@Override  
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
throws ServletException, IOException {  
processRequest(request, response);  
}  


@Override  
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
throws ServletException, IOException {  
processRequest(request, response);  
}  


@Override  
public String getServletInfo() {  
return "Short description";  
}  
}
```

Comment: Can you trim this down to the part that's able to demonstrate the problem? It's not necessary to paste your entire application page in here.

Comment: Check this link http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/Insertdatatoatable.htm

Comment: Try printing out the errors to see if you have any. Just use `System.out.println(e);` in your catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a vocabulary point : class `DatabaseConnection` is not a servlet. But you should read (or read again) a good tutorial on JDBC :

- you do not correctly test the different operations to properly close what you have opened in case of error
- you do not close what you have opened if things go right
- you copy parameters from the request in an insert query - google around for *SQL injection* to understand whay you should never do that
- you do not log the result from `executeUpdate`
- you hide the exception that can occur but writing "Error" instead of the full stacktrace that could help to understand what happens.

You should begin by writing a Junit test to control that you can successfully write to database outside of the servlet context. And only when that part works correctly, you integrate the persistence code with into the web application.

Answer (score 0):

remove localhost and try 127.0.0.1 ... it worked for me

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/music","root","");
```

Comment: Please add some explanations please